# Open all pages in directory in one page

Tags: php

I've done a lot of searching for possible ways to do this without success.

I have a directory with all the needed pages. I would like to have them all opened in one page so that I can then print them to pdf.

```
/allpages

page1.php
page2.php
page3.php
.....
page33.php
```

Is this possible to do or would it be too much for any browser?

If you have another php idea to put all pages into pdf without to much additional software
installed on server I'm open for that also. I've looked at several Linux PDF set up’s but could not seem to get them working or they needed many additional packages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `include('yourpages');`

Comment: Tried that. They all jumble on top of each other.

Comment: You want to include all the pages, but they jumble on top of each other. That sounds like a layout issue, do each of these pages contain full markup? <html>.....</html>.. ?

Comment: Yes, I listed them all in a main.php <?php include "page1.php"; ?> one on each line. Then open main.php

Comment: Also tried the way Daan showed and they all came out on a single page.

Comment: You can't just send multiple documents (`<html><body>...</body></html>`) in the same request back to the browser. It will try and combine them all into a single one. What you could do is load them all up in iframes in a "parent" page, but then you'd need some JS to set their height. Maybe use a server-side HTML2PDF library and send the combined PDF to the browser?

Comment: That's why I was hoping there was an easy solution, but doesn’t look like there will be. Even thought of opening them all in browser tabs but there didn't seem to be a way to get the list and open. Firefox has a plug-in that will print all tabs to pdf.

Comment: I got it working. I'll post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Created a separate php and called them all. Other than that all the pages were displayed one
after the other.

```
<div id="Html5" style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:2px;width:696px;height:30px;z-index:9">
<iframe src ="page1.php" width="750" height="1100"> </iframe>
<iframe src ="page2.php" width="750" height="1100"> </iframe>
<iframe src ="page3.php" width="750" height="1100"> </iframe>
<iframe src ="page4.php" width="750" height="1100"> </iframe>
<iframe src ="page5.php" width="750" height="1100"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Well why would you `top:902px;`? That's the extra space above. `height="1100"` is a problem though. Are you sure all the pages are at most that height?

Comment: Yes, they are all at 1100 and that was also perfect when printed to PDF. They are all on their own page with nothing hanging into another page.